# Hosting a Unity3D game on Azure Websites

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble running my Unity3D web player build on Windows Azure websites. I've uploaded the two files generated by Unity, an html file and a .unity3d. However, when I try to run the website, even if Unity Web Player is already installed.

I uploaded my files via FTPS to the \site\wwwroot directory which seems to be correct. But if I run the website, the unity web player says the object can't be found.

I read somewhere that I have to change the MIME settings for the website with something like this:

```
<staticContent> 
<mimeMap fileExtension=".unity3d" mimeType="application/vnd.unity" /> 
</staticContent>
```

But I don't know how to change the MIME settings or if that's even possible from the dashboard in Windows Azure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, I just came across it today :).

What you should do to change the MIME settings for your website is to add a file named web.config in the root folder of your Azure website ( / ).

The file web.config should contain the following in order to allow Unity3d to work (as you previously stated)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".unity3d" mimeType="application/vnd.unity" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Once the file has been uploaded, restart your website from the portal and it should work perfectly.

Have a nice day

Mike